# What is iOS “General” mobile data use?

Tags: ios, cellular-data

I set up a new iPhone and am using a 1 GB data plan while traveling. I thought I would use it to just check my email and use gps maps while driving, and I thought this might be sufficient for three weeks.

However, after 4 days, all the data is used up. So I went into Settings - Cellular to see what used up all the data.

I expected it to be the maps (I took a one-hour drive) but according to the settings maps only used 6 MB, while “General” accounts for a whopping 1 GB, basically the entire data amount.

What in the world is this “General” category?  What kind of data is this?

I have background app updates disabled for most my apps if it matters. In the future I will have times when I want to minimize data usage again, so I’d like to understand what’s going on here.

[image: data usage] [image: data usage breakdown]